# Symfony Call to a member function getTimezone() on integer

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, timezone, orocrm

I want to convert the table of column: created_on from DateTime type to Bigint type. 
Such that it saves the current Date-Time value into MySQL Database Table.

From the the controller as I'm trying to call the method

```
$smiledMoment->setCreatedValues();
```

In my Entity file:

```
     /**
     * @param integer $created_on
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_on", type="bigint")
     */

    protected $created_on;
     /**
     * Set created_on
     *
     * @param integer $created_on
     * @return SmiledMoment
     */
    public function setCreatedOn($created_on)
    {

        $datetime = (array) $created_on;
        $dat = strtotime($datetime['date']);
        //echo $dat->format('d/m/Y');
        //exit;
        $this->created_on = $dat;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get created_on
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedOn()
    {
        return $this->created_on;
    }

    /**
     * Set initial value for created_on/modified_on values
     *
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setCreatedValues()
    {

        $this->setCreatedOn(new \DateTime());
    }
```

***From the $dat value is generated as 1517900080 (i.e Timestamp value).

But Unfortunately I'm getting an error as***

> FatalThrowableError in UTCDateTimeType.php line 25: Call to a member
>   function getTimezone() on integer

Comment: This seems like a `timestamp` and not `datetime`.

Comment: @AmitMerchant Yes! i.e Unix Timestamp

Comment: So, you probably want to convert it to `datetime` first.

Comment: `getCreatedOn` claims it is returning `DateTime` but in your code it would be returning a `BigInt`. So it can't adjust the timezone.

Comment: @hcoat Kindly can you assist me with the coding regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the UNIX timestamp to a DateTime object first like so: `$dt = new DateTime('@' . $timestamp);`

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to handle this, but if we continue on the same path your on we will return a `DateTime` object. To do this you will need to convert your `int` back to time.

```
/**
 * Get created_on
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getCreatedOn()
{
    $date = new DateTime();
    return $date->setTimestamp($created_on);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to store date in the MySql database as integer - the most proper way to achieve this - is to create custom Doctrine's mapping type.
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html

To get some clues of how to do that, look at the default implementation of doctrine's DateTimeType:
https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateTimeType.php